# Is Google`s FusedLocationAPI always reliable ? (mock location , spoofing , etc .. )

Tags: android, google-maps, locationmanager

There are a number of workarounds for detecting the possibility of a fake location being returned by the LocationManager API. those include checking if the mock location setting is enabled and checking the list of installed apps for the ones using the mock location permission. if any of the above happens we could go with removing the TestProvider from the current LocationManager instance and getting a location again, just in case the api returns bogus results. however the above approach wont work with the FusedLocationAPI. is it always granted to return the real location ? or should i consider changing my code to use the LocationManager ?
because of the nature of product i'm working on, it is necessary to be sure of the location.

thanks in advance